# Importing Excel into Hadoop via C#

Tags: c#, hadoop

I'm trying to determine the best way to import a set of files into our hadoop environment at work via a C# console app.

Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel I'm importing each file into a DataTable and I have a successful connection to Hadoop established by using the Hortonworks Hive ODBC driver. However I'm trying to figure out the correct way to create a table in hadoop from the DataTable. If I was using MSSQL I would use SqlBulkCopy. Any insight into the correct way to do this would be great. I've hit a brick wall in regards to researching an approach here.